# How to structure the JS? Put the code in a unique file or require the necessary JS code in the file where its used?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Do you know if **is better to have a unique file with all JS** or **is better in each file require the specific JS that is necessary for that specific page**?

The project sould stay better structured requiring the JS specific for each file.

But in terms of performance do you know if is basically the same or not?

Comment: depends on the size of the js file i its big and necesary ony for that page the use it ony on that page, if your js file is small its better if you compile them in a single file that the browser will cache between pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small JS snippets is always better to implement it only on pages you need.

But, for big classes, framework or huge functions is better use single file with an CDN. That way is better performance and finaly better to maitenance and for developing is better to stay organized.

As second, in single file you can easily do minified version fully automated.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer creating a unique JavaScript file and then linking it to the html file. It is the most efficient and organized way of structuring your code. But if the amount of code is very small and only required for that single page, inline JavaScript is preferred.

Performance: External JavaScript is always faster because the browser can cache an external file but Inline JavaScript will always be loaded afresh and hence is slower.